# "I like listening to music" and "I like to listen to music" - is there any difference?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, licensing

When speaking about my hobby, should I say:

> 1. I like listening to music.
> 2. I like to listen to music.

Do both mean the same? Is any of these sentences grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short: **there is almost no difference when using them in that sentence, and both are grammatical and common.**

In general, the "Xing" form is slightly more casual whereas the "to X" form is a bit more abstract. In the form "I like..." it's essentially the same, but the difference becomes a lot clearer when you use it as a subject:

> Listening to music is the best hobby

vs.

> To listen to music is the best hobby

The first sounds like you are speaking from personal experience, whereas the second sounds more like you are making a philosophical or poetic statement.

Slightly beyond the scope of your question, but one last thing to note is that there are some verbs that *require* one form or the other, and that will overrule any other consideration:

> **I enjoy listening to music** [correct]
>
> I enjoy to listen to music [wrong]

and

> **I want to listen to music** [correct]
>
> I want listening to music [wrong]

Comment: What are those verbs that have a particular requirement I mean besides the mentioned `want` and `enjoy`. Intuitively it seems to be somehow linked with the `process` vs `fact` thing i.e. `like` is ok with both process and fact but `enjoy` only makes sense with a `process` and `want` does only fit some `fact`.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford Guide to English Grammar by John Eastwood says in section 121.2:
Some verbs can take either a to-infinitive or a gerund with almost no difference. 
Eastwood has the following list:

like love perfer hate

begin commence start continue cease

intend propose

can't bear

bother (I don't bother washing up/to wash up.)

He has some minor annotations to some of these verbs which I don't think very important.